# Huawei Mate 10 Pro phone doesn't find beacons with altbeacon. Other phones do

Tags: android, bluetooth, beacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I am using altbeacon: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/
I bind my beaconManager. and then I call this:

```
   public void startListeningForBeacons(RangeNotifier rangeNotifier) {
    try {
        Region region = new Region("all-beacons-region", null, null, null);
        // Tells the BeaconService to start looking for beacons that match the passed Region object
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Specifies a class that should be called each time the BeaconService gets ranging data, once per second by default
    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier);
}
```

Which starts calling this function inside my application class:

```
  @Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(final Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
    if (beacons.size() > 0) {
        Log.i("BluetoothService", "BluetoothService region The first beacon I see is about " + beacons.iterator().next().getDistance() + " meters away.");
        if (didRangeBeaconsCallback != null)
            didRangeBeaconsCallback.rangeCalled(beacons, region);
    }else {
        Log.i("BluetoothService", "BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: " + beacons.size());
        if(PSBluetoothService.getInstance(PSApplicationClass.this).beaconUUID != null){
            if (didRangeBeaconsCallback != null)
                didRangeBeaconsCallback.rangeCalled(null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

But a lot of times, I get back o collection of size 0. Even thought I have 2 beacons in range.
I also tried with a LG Nexus 5 and a LeEco LePro2 and both return the correct list of beacons. What might go wrong when it comes to the Huawei?

If it helps, this is the list of beacon layouts I configure:

```
   //sets the types of beacons that the library is searching for
public void setNeededTypesOfBeacons() {
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.ALTBEACON_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
}
```

And I use this beacons: https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/3-pcs-BLE-4-0-Base-Station-Ebeoo-iBeacon-USB/32752285433.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.g1aZkv

This is a picture showing what it finds, compared to the others:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/5FNgB6ARACpywWv/upload.png

## EDIT:

Made a sample app, just with this logic, if it helps: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ddt9mhn7zdi9gd/Beacon.zip?dl=0

Even when leaving it scan for a long time, still no results, when it doesn't find them:

```
03-20 12:30:24.542: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:25.644: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:26.749: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:27.855: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:28.960: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:30.071: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:31.174: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:32.277: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:33.379: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:34.486: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:35.588: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:36.696: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:37.803: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:38.906: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:40.012: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:41.210: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:42.313: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:43.418: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:44.522: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:45.628: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:46.734: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:47.839: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:48.943: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:50.061: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:50.061: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:51.165: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:52.268: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:53.372: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
03-20 12:30:54.476: I/BluetoothService(10806): BluetoothService region NO BEACONS: 0
```

Comment: Do the phones where it works OK have Android 8+?  Do you get detections on the Huawei reliably in the foreground?  What version of the Android Beacon Library are you using?

Comment: @davidgyoung I am using: 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'
The other 2 phones have Android 6.0.
I can connect the phone to bluetooth headsets or other phones. But because I didn't make the detection work for beacons on it.

Comment: You say "a lot of times I get back o collection of size 0."  This seems to suggest it works *sometimes* on the Huawei device.  Can you please describe the pattern of when it works vs. when it does not?

Comment: Well, I have a retry button, which disconnects, rebinds the beacon manager, start searching again, for 5 seconds. after what it shows the results, or "No Beacons Found"  just like in the picture. with the Retry button.
If I retry 10 times, It will find then once.
My problem is that once finding one. i need to get the BluetoothDevice, change the name of it, change the uuid (on list item pressed). And when that is done, I scan again for beacons, and try to find it.
After the uuid and name (or just name, doesn't matter) get's changed, and I search again.

Comment: Cause normally it would only "find" a collection every 10 tries. of course my second try is going to fail, cause what are the odds of this working 1 after another. if I can barely get a 5-10% change of finding them

Comment: @davidgyoung I included in the question a dropbox link to a zip with a sample project, with this logic. Maybe it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments below the question, the detection is *intermittent* on Huawei and the code only has a 5-10% chance of detecting a beacon in 5 seconds of scanning, at which point the code gives up.

There are some bluetooth chips that are slow to detect the first beacon after starting scanning.   This may be a hardware limitation that you must learn to live with.

I would suggest you rework the code to:

1. Look for beacons for much longer than 5 seconds and show results as soon as you find one.  This way it will be fast on fast devices and slow on slow devices.
2. Don't unbind from the beacon manager until the app goes to the background.  This way, it is already scanning in case you hit retry, and there won't be a delay in starting up scanning.
3. If you have control over the configuration of the hardware beacon, make sure it is transmitting at the highest rate possible.  Some beacons are set to transmit only once every 1-5 seconds, which decreases the chance of detecting a packet within a short time interval.   The more often you make the beacon transmit, the greater the odds of it getting detected within 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, I increased the time to 15 seconds, but so far it's the same. I will try removing the unbind, and going to let you know what happens

Comment: Nope, even if I leave it indefinitely. Edited and added a log on my question.

Comment: What do you see if you run the library's reference app on the Huawei: https://github.com/altbeacon/android-beacon-library-reference

Comment: It works, it was cause of the Battery Settings / it has a Launch mode, and if you do not set the app to be handler "manually" and set it to work in background and autostart. it won't work. Something similar to how a power saver works

Answer (score 0):

Any device with Android 4.3+ and a Bluetooth Low Energy chipset can detect beacons with this library. As of August 2017, this is approximately 92 percent of Android devices according to the Google Play Store.

To transmit as a beacon, Android 5.0+ and firmware supporting Bluetooth Low Energy Peripheral Mode are required.

> To find out if your smart phone or tablet can work with Bluetooth LE:
>   Go to the Google Play store and install the free app “[BLE Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magicalboy.btd)” on
>   your Android device. The app is simple – it tells you whether your
>   device supports Bluetooth LE or not and that is all it does.

I cant test your code on Mate10 because I didn't have one now but I think your problem for about the android 8 read this link about the changes on android 8

http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8

Apps that use the library will need to upgrade to version 2.12+ in order to detect in the background on Android 8 devices. Version 2.13+ adds further enhancements for Android 8.1 restrictions of scanning with the screen off.

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'
}
```

Comment: I edited my title. The issue is encountered on an Huawei Mate 10 Pro, with Android 8.0 which is new and does support BLE

Comment: Also, if I use the BluetoothAdapter, and discovery, I can pair, bond, and even change the characteristics of the Beacon. Only with ranging for them, I have issues

Comment: @rosualin check mate10 with BLE checker please

Comment: I mean I already player with it in LightBlue and BeaconManager. Tried BLE Checker now and it says it is supported.

Comment: And there are moments where it does find 1 beacon, but it takes a long time, and because it's ranging permanently, it will disappear relatively quickly. I'm trying to understand why I don't get the signal from it, permanently, like on the Nexus or LeEco

Comment: @rosualin If you use the latest version, the library will use a JobScheduler instead of a long-running service to process scans on apps installed on Android 8+.

Comment: I was using: `compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.12.4'`
Will try now with:   `compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'`
Do I need to change anything else?

Comment: @rosualin no  compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+' is enough

Comment: Then still the same issue. The picture I've put inside the question is using 2+